# Execute Oracle SQL query by input Identification number inside entry box and pressing button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I'm new for python. I try to develop a program, which executes some Oracle SQL query in the database. So the concept is next: I have entry box here I type a Personal ID, then I must press the button which collects inputted Personal ID from the entry box and injects it into the already prepared SQL query, then the query will be executed and select data about Personal ID owner. Now I stucked, I'm not able to collect data from the entry box. please help. Thanks a lot.

```
import tkinter as ibumt
from tkinter import simpledialog
import cx_Oracle

def get_pn():
    global pn
    result = simpledialog.askstring
    pn = result # pn is like 01000476891

sql_pn = """ Select cl.EXTERNALID as CLIENT_NO , upc.USERNAME, ipe.FIRSTNAMEINLATIN as FIRSTNAME, ipe.LASTNAMEINLATIN as LASTNAME, ipe.IDENTIFICATIONNUMBER
where 1=1 and cpc3con.CONTRACTSUBTYPE = 'STB'
and dcu.STATUS='ACTIVE'
and ipe.IDENTIFICATIONNUMBER = :pn and rownum = 1 """""
#ipe.IDENTIFICATIONNUMBER = :pn << pn must automatically replaced by inputted pn number for example: 01000476891

con = cx_Oracle.connect('Test/test@160.28.76.89:1521/STBDB')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(sql_pn, [pn])
for line in cur:
    print(line)
cur.close()
con.close()

width = 350
heigh = 600

root = ibumt.Tk()
root.title('ibumt')
root.resizable(height=False, width=False)

canvas = ibumt.Canvas(root, height=heigh, width=width)
canvas.pack()

frame_hider = ibumt.Frame(root, bg='gray')

frame_hider.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.005, relheight=0.07,relwidth=0.99, anchor='n')

label_hider = ibumt.Label(frame_hider, text="User Management Tool",   fg='black', bg='gray')
label_hider.config(font=("Courier", 9))
label_hider.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.25, relheight=0.5, relwidth=0.7)

frame_mid = ibumt.Frame(root, bg='dark gray')
frame_mid.place(relx=0.005, rely=0.08, relheight=0.6, relwidth=0.99)

label_pn = ibumt.Label(frame_mid, text="Personal Number :",   fg='white', bg='dark gray')
label_pn.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.02, relheight=0.08, relwidth=0.34)

entry_pn = ibumt.Entry(frame_mid, bg='white')
entry_pn.place(relx=0.37, rely=0.02, relheight=0.08, relwidth=0.35)

button_pn = ibumt.Button(frame_mid, text="Check Client", bg='gray',command=get_pn)
button_pn.place(relx=0.74, rely=0.02, relheight=0.08, relwidth=0.25)

label_output_pn_cn = ibumt.Label(frame_mid, fg='white', bg='white')
label_output_pn_cn.place(relx=0.009, rely=0.225, relheight=0.76,relwidth=0.983)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. I see some values like `Lsep` in your post? Is it just a line seperator?

Comment: Hello, thanks. Yes, I just use Line separator, because when I try to use SQL query with triple """ """ I'm not able to modify defined variable >  ipe.IDENTIFICATIONNUMBER = :pn < inside """"select"""". 

So I try to use "select\nwehre" and in this case I'm able to modify ipe.IDENTIFICATIONNUMBER = :pn < defined :pn inside select.

Can I change variable inside triple """ """ somehow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a StringVar() object.

```py
import tkinter as ibumt
from tkinter import simpledialog
import cx_Oracle

def get_pn():
    global pn
    result = my_stringvar.get() #this will set result to whatever is in the entry box at the time
    pn = result # pn is like 01000476891

sql_pn = """ Select cl.EXTERNALID as CLIENT_NO , upc.USERNAME, ipe.FIRSTNAMEINLATIN as FIRSTNAME, ipe.LASTNAMEINLATIN as LASTNAME, ipe.IDENTIFICATIONNUMBER
where 1=1 and cpc3con.CONTRACTSUBTYPE = 'STB'
and dcu.STATUS='ACTIVE'
and ipe.IDENTIFICATIONNUMBER = :pn and rownum = 1 """""
#ipe.IDENTIFICATIONNUMBER = :pn << pn must automatically replaced by inputted pn number for example: 01000476891

con = cx_Oracle.connect('Test/test@160.28.76.89:1521/STBDB')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(sql_pn, [pn])
for line in cur:
    print(line)
cur.close()
con.close()

width = 350
heigh = 600

root = ibumt.Tk()
root.title('ibumt')
root.resizable(height=False, width=False)

my_stringvar = ibumt.StringVar() #create an instance of StringVar()

canvas = ibumt.Canvas(root, height=heigh, width=width)
canvas.pack()

frame_hider = ibumt.Frame(root, bg='gray')

frame_hider.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.005, relheight=0.07,relwidth=0.99, anchor='n')

label_hider = ibumt.Label(frame_hider, text="User Management Tool",   fg='black', bg='gray')
label_hider.config(font=("Courier", 9))
label_hider.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.25, relheight=0.5, relwidth=0.7)

frame_mid = ibumt.Frame(root, bg='dark gray')
frame_mid.place(relx=0.005, rely=0.08, relheight=0.6, relwidth=0.99)

label_pn = ibumt.Label(frame_mid, text="Personal Number :",   fg='white', bg='dark gray')
label_pn.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.02, relheight=0.08, relwidth=0.34)

entry_pn = ibumt.Entry(frame_mid, bg='white', textvariable=my_stringvar)# you have to set the textvariable to your StringVar() instance.
entry_pn.place(relx=0.37, rely=0.02, relheight=0.08, relwidth=0.35) 

button_pn = ibumt.Button(frame_mid, text="Check Client", bg='gray',command=get_pn)
button_pn.place(relx=0.74, rely=0.02, relheight=0.08, relwidth=0.25)

label_output_pn_cn = ibumt.Label(frame_mid, fg='white', bg='white')
label_output_pn_cn.place(relx=0.009, rely=0.225, relheight=0.76,relwidth=0.983)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for answer, But I how it helps me in that case ?

Comment: You wanted to know how to get the information from the entry box. That is how. If you are having another issue. Give the error message or something. You can debug where the code is failing by temporarily adding print() statements.